# factory_boy: passing model instances for a RelatedFactory

Tags: django, factory-boy

I figured instead of passing data to a factory's RelatedFactory in the form of `ATTR__SUBATTR`, you should also be able to just directly pass already existing instances. Unless I'm missing something very obvious, this just doesn't seem to work.
Have a look:

```
class Owner(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(Owner, null = True, related_name = 'items')

class ItemFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

class OwnerFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner
    items = factory.RelatedFactory(ItemFactory, 'owner')

item = Item.objects.create(name='Foo')
alice = OwnerFactory(name='Alice', items__name='Bar')
alice.items.all()
<QuerySet [<Item: Bar>]>
bob = OwnerFactory(name='Bob', items=item) # or items = [item] doesn't matter
bob.items.all()
<QuerySet []>
```

Been working on making my factories nice and DRY and hit this roadblock. Wrote my own adaption of `RelatedFactory` that allows for multiple values to be handled at once, which works fine if you are creating new objects in the process - but not if you are using already existing ones.

Example that works: `OwnerFactory(items__name=['Foo','Bar'])=> Foo and Bar in owner.items`.
Example that does not work: `OwnerFactory(items=[foo,bar])=> owner.items is empty`
Note that I have used the default RelatedFactory in the big example at the top.

I have been all over the documentation for factory_boy the entire day, but couldn't find a solution and tunnel vision has taken over now, prohibiting any new insight.

Comment: Something to check; ensure you use `DjangoModelFactory` in all factories. I spent way too much time since I was using `factory.Factory` in a few

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are looking for http://factoryboy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes.html#simple-many-to-many-relationship

```
class ItemFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Item

class OwnerFactory(factory.django.DjangoModelFactory):
    class Meta:
        model = Owner

    @factory.post_generation
    def items(self, create, extracted, **kwargs):
        if not create:
            # Simple build, do nothing.
            return

        if extracted:
            # A list of items were passed in, use them
            for item in extracted:
                self.items.add(item)
```

Comment: This does help; assuming a call like this: `OwnerFactory(items=item, items__name=['Foo','Bar'])`, then `extracted` will be the object `item` and kwargs will contain `{'name': ['Foo', 'Bar']}`. It just strikes me as weird that, by default, `RelatedFactory` is perfectly capable of creating new related objects, but cannot use existing ones - and `PostGeneration` can use existing instances but cannot create any. Guess it comes down to implementing a way that can do both myself.